# Http WebRequest with Hebrew characters (SQL Server CLR sp)

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, get, sqlclr

I've prepared a CLR stored procedure in order to send GET requests for SMS (messaging) web service. This is the code:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void HttpGet(SqlString uri, out SqlString textResponse)
{
    Uri webUri = new Uri(uri.Value);

    HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webUri);
    webReq.Method = "GET";

    WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    using (dataStream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        using (reader)
        {
            textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send the following request:

```
http://serviceaddress/SMSManager/msgSend.jsp?msg=עברית&to=sms:050-1234567&encoding=windows-1255
```

For some reason the message i'm getting is in gibberish.

- I'd tried sending requests with Hebrew letters to other web services and it worked fine.
- I'd tried URL encoding the Hebrew part and it didn't work either. I tried changing the requested encoding to 'utf8' or omitting it. didn't work.
- I tried using exactly the same URL (with Hebrew letters) with an OLE Automation procedure. It worked.

I would welcome any advice about how to continue or how to fix the problem.

Thanks you.

Comment: I tried using exactly the same URL (with Hebrew letters) with an OLE Automation procedure. It worked.

Comment: You can specify an encoding for the `StreamReader`.  Use `new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);` (or whatever your encoding is)

Comment: Doesn't that apply only to the response?

Comment: Is this still an issue? And is that request URI what you are passing into the CLR Stored Procedure? What is the exact call you are making to the `HttpGet` proc?

Comment: I actually cannot remember. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You must encode your URL. Look at the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)